# MySQL column manipulation nonsense

Tags: mysql, sql

For the sake of example, I have a column of INTs that looks like this:

```
column1  
1  
2  
3   
4   
5
```

I have the following code:

```
SELECT column1+1
FROM table
```

which returns exactly what you'd expect:

```
column1  
2  
3  
4   
5   
6
```

On the other hand if I do:

```
SELECT column1+AVG(column1)
FROM table
```

I get complete nonsense, a *single* row. I sincerely apologize if this is basic but, I have no idea what's going on here. I've tried using CAST on every possible combination of "colum1+AVG(colum1)" but it still returns nonsense.

Comment: Can u try `SELECT column1 + (SELECT AVG(column1) FROM table) FROM table`?

Comment: @Gosu: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 2):

When you have `avg()` in the `select`, you are telling SQL that you have an aggregation query.  Without a `group by`, you get exactly one row.

You probably intend something like this:

```
SELECT column1 + (SELECT AVG(column1) FROM table)
FROM table;
```

Comment: Thanks!! A quick question: why is it that you don't need an alias for the avg table that you've selected?

Comment: @AlexR. . . . I'm not sure what your question really is.  You don't need an alias for tables in all circumstances.  You don't need an alias for the column in a scalar subquery ( a subquery that returns one column and at most one row), because the value is converted to a scalar.